# Schengen transit visa for a Sri Lankan

Tags: visas, transit, italy, transit-visas, sri-lankan-citizens

Does a Sri Lankan national who holds a valid US visa need an airport transit visa to transit through an airport in Italy?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_in_the_European_Union) suggests that he or she would *not* need an airport transit visa (Sri Lankan nationals in general do but holding a valid US visa qualifies for an exemption to this requirement). Maybe some Sri Lankan national will share his or her experience but the best would probably be to confirm that with an Italian consulate.

Comment: I checked the consulate's website. It says the same thing: That a Sri Lankan national does not need a transit visa if they have a valid US visa. But Can I take what's on a website to be their official standing?. Here is the [Website](http://www.conschicago.esteri.it/Consolato_Chicago/Menu/I_Servizi/Per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/airport_transit.htm). I e mailed the consulate, and they directed me to the website without saying anything :(

Comment: @Karlson I do not see any mention of flying inside Schengen area. Furthermore, we indeed have no question regarding citizens of Sri Lanka and a couple other countries.

Comment: The question I listed discusses transit visa requirements for citizens of India but the link also mentions transit visa requirements for citizens of Sri Lanka, which also states that holders of a valid US VISA are exempted from Transit visa requirements.

Comment: I wonder what the best way to make generic versions of some of these frequently asked questions would be. Specifically for when we get several version with varying citizenship and destination but for which there is a common answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Citizens of some countries must have a Schengen airport transit visa](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ%3aL:2009:243:0001:01%3aEN%3aHTML) to go through the airside zone of Schengen airports. This concerns the citizens of Sri Lanka, but also Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Nigeria, Pakistan, and Somalia.

For these citizens, exceptions exist if they hold a resident permit in some other country, namely the US, Canada, Andorra, Japan, or San Marino.

In your case, only the following US residence permits are accepted as valid forms to transit through the airport: form I-551, form I-327, a Resident Alien card, a permit to re-enter, or a valid temporary residence stamp in a valid passport.

If you have one of these documents, you will be allowed to TRANSIT through any Schengen airport (i.e. in Italy), but you should not leave the international zone (your origin and destination should be out of Schengen too).

If you plan to enter Italy or to fly to another Schengen country, you need a visa.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So since I have an F-1 visa valid for 5 years (multiple entry) I will be able to transit through Italy right? (I fly from STL to Rome to Colombo)?.

Comment: Note that in addition to the countries you have listed, individual Schengen states are allowed to require transit visas for citizens of additional countries to transit through their airports. For example, [Germany requires transit visas for Indian citizens](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/Infoservice/FAQ/VisumFuerD/33-Transit.html?nn=480902) among others.

Answer (score 1):

I hold a Sri lankan passport and I transited through Zurich last December. I had around a 9 hour transit. They did not ask me for a transit visa. I think it'll be fine as long as you have a booked flight ticket out of the country, alhough you cannot leave the transit waiting area.

Comment: Welcome, Jay. My edit was just a few spelling corrections and punctuation.