# Do I need a transit visa through Zurich with a Canadian visa?

Tags: schengen, transit, zurich

Do I need a transit visa through Zurich with a Canadian visa travelling from Botswana?

Comment: @Dirty-flow We have many Schengen questions but the whole difficulty is figuring out which one of them is a “duplicate” (i.e. what rule is relevant for a given scenario/nationality), whether the Canadian visa makes a difference, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Many previous questions addressed related problems:

- [Schengen transit visa for a Sri Lankan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20666/schengen-transit-visa-for-a-sri-lankan/20672#20672)
- [Do I need an airport transit visa through Switzerland (Schengen) if I have no Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19137/do-i-need-an-airport-transit-visa-through-switzerland-schengen-if-i-have-no-sc)

The most important thing to know is that Switzerland is part of the Schengen area so you should look up [rules that apply to your situation in the Schengen area](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/). You also wrote that you are traveling “from” Botswana but in fact this does not make any difference. What counts is your nationality/which passport you are holding.

Assuming you are a citizen of Botswana, since it is not an annex IV country and is not, as far as I know, subject to additional restrictions from Switzerland, you can in principle transit visa-free **if both of your flights come from or go to destinations outside of the Schengen area** so as to allow you to stay in the international transit zone of the airport. However, if you have a long transit, want to stay in the city or connect to another Schengen airport, you would need a regular transit visa. See [US green card holder: Do I need a transit visa when my journey includes a flight within a Schengen country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21678/us-green-card-holder-do-i-need-a-transit-visa-when-my-journey-includes-a-flight)

<s>If your nationality did not allow you to transit visa-free, the Canadian visa would not necessarily be relevant *per se* (beyond the fact that you obviously need a visa for your onward travel) as I think that only some types of *residence permits*/long-term visas provide an exemption from the airport transit visa in the Schengen area, where applicable.</s> (EDITED: Not sure this is correct but, as I explained above, it's not relevant for Botswana nationals in any case.)

Contacting the airline, airport or Swiss consulate in advance might be a good idea in any case.